How to get Transfer Function from R to Y?
How to get Transfer Function from R to Y?
I can group G2 and G3 up by doing G2/1+G2G3 Correct? Dont really know what to do from there

Are you not allowed to simply solve Y=((R+D*GF-Y)*G1+D+Y*G3)*G2 for Y?

@Anon - You are asking "I can group G2 and G3 up by doing G2/1+G2G3, Correct?" M answer: I don`t know because I am not sure if you have forgotten some negative signs at the summing junctions?

Anon, let me see how you worked out the only expression you presented. Take it one step at a time, as short of a step as possible, and explain your thinking as you proceed.

I'll take the following as your question:

I can group G2 and G3 up by doing G2/1+G2G3 Correct?

(The rest is wide open and you haven't shown any work to examine.)
I believe your approach was to perform the following step:

Then we would say that:
$$\begin{align*}
Y&=G_2\cdot\left(T+G_3\cdot Y\right)
\\\\
&=G_2\cdot T+G_2\cdot G_3\cdot Y
\\\\
Y-G_2\cdot G_3\cdot Y&=G_2\cdot T
\\\\
Y\cdot\left(1-G_2\cdot G_3\right)&=G_2\cdot T
\\\\
Y &= T\cdot\frac{G_2}{1-G_2\cdot G_3}
\end{align*}$$
I believe you got the sign wrong in the denominator. I followed your approach as I understand it. Just not your result.
I think the answer is this (so far as you have proceeded, anyway):

Note the difference in the sign I'm using versus what you wrote in your question.
This is just a start, of course. But hopefully this helps.
It's now up to you to suggest the next step.
My own feeling is that you solve Y=((R+D*GF-Y)*G1+D+Y*G3)*G2 for Y. That will work fine and is the direct approach.
But if you need to take steps along the way, such as the one you suggested and I quoted above, to show your mastery of incremental steps, then please do so. I won't argue.
But you do need to show your work for the rest of the problem. If not, I can't help you on those steps.
